# Pods terminated immediately from Jenkins to Kubernetes cluster

Tags: windows, minikube, kubernetes-jenkins-plugin

I have jenkins running on Windows as a service on 127.0.0.1:8080
and minikube running on 192.168.99.101
below is the pipeline for Jenkins job

```
podTemplate(
  activeDeadlineSeconds: 240,
  name: 'default',
  inheritFrom: 'default',
  nodeSelector: 'key1=value1,kubernetes.io/hostname=minikube',
  containers: [
  containerTemplate(name: 'maven', image: 'maven:3.3.9-jdk-8-alpine', ttyEnabled: true, command: 'cat' ),
  containerTemplate(name: 'jnlp', image: 'jenkins/jnlp-slave:3.35-2-alpine', args: '${computer.jnlpmac} ${computer.name}')
]) {

node(POD_LABEL) {
    stage('Get a Maven project') {
        git 'https://github.com/<project>.git/'
        container('maven') {
            stage('Build a Maven project') {
                sh 'mvn -B -gs ./settings.xml clean install'
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

The following are the logs for from the kubernetes:

```
$ kubectl get -a pods --watch
Flag --show-all has been deprecated, will be removed in an upcoming release
NAME                  READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
default-7r0n8-b2sxx   0/2       Pending   0          0s
default-7r0n8-b2sxx   0/2       Pending   0         0s
default-7r0n8-b2sxx   0/2       ContainerCreating   0         0s
default-7r0n8-b2sxx   2/2       Running   0         0s
default-7r0n8-b2sxx   1/2       Error     0         1s
default-7r0n8-18cv6   0/2       Pending   0         0s
default-7r0n8-18cv6   0/2       Pending   0         0s
default-7r0n8-18cv6   0/2       ContainerCreating   0         0s
default-7r0n8-18cv6   2/2       Running   0         0s
default-7r0n8-18cv6   1/2       Error     0         2s
default-7r0n8-0kz80   0/2       Pending   0         0s
default-7r0n8-0kz80   0/2       Pending   0         0s
default-7r0n8-0kz80   0/2       ContainerCreating   0         0s
default-7r0n8-0kz80   2/2       Running   0         0s
default-7r0n8-0kz80   1/2       Error     0         1s
```

The following is the console's output from the jenkins job

[image]

The pods are getting killed and recreated each time.

Please Can anyone help how to resolve this issue?
Any help would be appreciated.

pod logs

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is Jenkins version , and k8s plugin version ?

Comment: jenkins = 2.235.2,   
k8s plugin = 1.26.4

Comment: what baout k8s plugin ?

Comment: also let me know , if some other fields are required in pipeline ..

Comment: kubernetes-version = v1.10.0

Comment: minikube version = minikube version: v0.28.2

Comment: I had some issues to connect pods after upgrade the plugin , once I revert to 1.25.4 it works , maybe it's your issue ? 

did you enable to connect pods before or it's the first time ?

Comment: please note that jenkins is running outside local k8 cluster . this is my first time setup

Comment: did you able to run pods before , or it's your first setup ?

Comment: yes this is my first setup, which minikube version you used?

Comment: i am still facing the same issue , the pods keep on getting created and destroyed , for the 1.25.4 version

Comment: the slave pod comes for  a while and vanishes off :=  
Still waiting to schedule task
default-llqqz-18ltt’ is offline

Comment: Could you provide logs from thoses poses? `kubectl logs <pod-name>` or this `job` YAML `kubectl get job <job-name> -o yaml` ? Is it possible to upgrade Kubernetes version?

Comment: theres nothing much in the logs , pods get created and then gets killed immediately. also the agents dont start automatically , i have to manually downloaded .jnlp but it gets killed and another one starts.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem since yesterday. Navigate to Configure Clouds --> kubernetes --> Pod Template. Set Pod Retention as 'Always'. Pods will stay in error status. You can get the pod logs with command kubectl logs  --all-containers and see the error reason. In my case Jenkins URL   and Jenkins Tunnel is not set properly.

Refer to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DCkzdsffeh0

It gives details for jenkins and kubernetes plugin configuration

Comment: Did you setup the environment same as mine?running Jenkins as windows service,  outside  minikube cluster

Comment: No, I have setup jenkins in GKE. jnlp container in the agent pod is not able to connect to Jenkis so new agent pod are getting created. I believe it is related to the jenkins URL. In my case after I provided correct Jenkins URL it worked for me. For jenkins as window service check if setting Jenkins URL to http://<your_ip_address>:8080 works.

Comment: Please try the following: 1. For the agent pod created from jenkins, type kubectl exec -it <<pod name>> -- bash. 2. Inside the pod bash, curl http://<<jenkins url>>. (e.g http://<<jenkins:8080>>). The curl command which works is the correct Jenkins url. Agent pod will be able to connect back to jenkins. Sorry I could not find time to set up minikube and check the exact url. Also try with http://<machine_ip_address>:8080 in curl command. If you succeed please let me know

Comment: The pod gets created and killed immediately, same thing repeats again and again as shown above.

Comment: the issue is inbound docker-agent is trying to ping jenkins master 127.0.0.1:8080, but this is not possible because containers are isolated from host applications.